# Microphone Nisuta NS-MIC180 Not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, microphone, input-devices

I use Windows and Ubuntu in my computer, and when I use the Microphone in Windows I just need to plug in into the side panel and it works!

But when I use Ubuntu, I tried to do the same, but nothing happens... I've look for [This is what I get when I run `alsamixer`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNKnD.png) and it shows mic volume... so I don't know if it recognize it or don't.

Do I need to download a driver or manually configurate it ? Because I haven't found a driver for this microphone while looking around on Internet.

Comment: Nothing to do with the mic; everything to do with the sound cards and settings. It could have something to do with it if it were USB which, in practice, means an external sound card. Not the case with yours. Just make sure the correct input is selected.

Comment: @CelticWarrior thanks for answering! Where do I correct the "input configuration" ? Do I have to do it from alsamixer ? Or from other site?